a que se debe este error 42703: column "enumsortorder" does not exist
Estoy desarrollando un servicio de windows con c# que lea un archivo de texto unas ventas e inserte en una tabla de postgres.
El servicio funciona bien en ambiente de desarrollo pero en la maquina de servidor donde lo quiero instalar dice 42703: column "enumsortorder" does not exist.
Alguna idea?

A muchos nos gusta el desafío de responder, pero no es necesario activar el "modo difícil". No hay problema ni restricciones para que nos des algunas pistas como sería el código que estas ejecutando o mejor aún un [MCVE], un ejemplo del archivo de texto y cualquier cosa que pueda ayudar a ayudarte
